# Delay hiding and showing ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I want to hide the action bar when an activity is started and when the user touches the screen show it for a few seconds, then hide it again.

What I have come up with is just below, but I want to know if there is anything better I could have done (ignoring some style issues: magic numbers, duplication of logic,etc).

And I am using actionbarsherlock.

Thanks

```
Runnable hideActionbarRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
            bar.hide();
        }
    };

    Runnable showActionbarRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
            bar.show();
        }
    };

    Runnable animateActionBarHide = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.postDelayed(hideActionbarRunnable,3000);
        }
    };

    Runnable animateActionBarShow = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(showActionbarRunnable);
            handler.postDelayed(hideActionbarRunnable,3000);
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG,"CameraActivity:  onResume called");

        Thread t = new Thread(animateActionBarHide);
        t.start();
    }
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {


        ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(animateActionBarShow);
            t.start();
        }
        else
        {
            Thread t = new Thread(animateActionBarHide);
            t.start();
        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Handler class has a method `postDelayed(Runnable r, long delayMillis)`. That would make it much shorter and much more elegant.